# How do I pass data in to initialise a package with eg a logger in python?

Tags: python, package

**Problem** (so I don't get stuck in X-Y): When initialising a package `A` I want to pass in the logger from the package importing `A`.

**My attempt at a solution:**

Making an `__init__()` function in the package body doesn't seem to work the way I think it could, importing with `import A(my_logger)` .

Calling `A.__init__(my_logger)` does set the variable correctly; however the other items in the package have already been imported and have the original values of the logger (which you have to set in order to build syntactically correct Python -- correct me if I'm wrong please). Therefore doing it this way is too late.

Anyone know how to do this? I need it done on import so I get the entire package with consistent values.

Comment: That isn't possible, it's not even supported syntactically in the [`import` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).

Comment: I think you are indeed stuck in X-Y.

Comment: The `__init__` for packages is a _script_ named `__init__.py` in the package's root directory — it's not a function and you can't explicitly call it.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's kind of the nature of the question: how do you pass arguments into packages, in (maybe) a similar way as you'd pass them into classes?

Comment: You don't pass arguments to something that is not defined yet, be it a module, a class or whatever.

Comment: You can't pass arguments to modules when you import them, either. Something like can often be accomplished by defining a module or package initialization function (named anything you like), and then calling it explicitly in the client code after importation.

Answer (score 3):

May be you should create `__init__.py` file in package `A`:

```
A/
    __init__.py
```

and use logger in `__init__.py` file, for example:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('__main__')
logger.debug("hello debug")
logger.error("hello error")
```

Other way, you can use package name:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug("hello debug")
logger.error("hello error")
```

and after import `A` get logger of package `A`

```
import A
logger_a = logging.getLogger('A')
```

I not understand for what it need, but I'm found solution for you:

importer_a.py:

```
import os
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('logger_importer_a')
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
os.environ['logger_for_a'] = logger.name
import A
```

A__init__.py:

```
import os
import logging
logger_from_importer = logging.getLogger(os.environ.get('logger_for_a'))
```

Please think about right project architecture and imports sequence.

Comment: Thanks for hte answer but this is the wrong way round. I need the logger from the importer of package `A` to be passed in to `A`, not the logger from package `A` passed into the importer.

Comment: @DavidBoshton may be it helps you. Look at update answer.